# Is there any number of type "double" which can be asserted as >0 but are actually positive

Tags: lua, roblox

I am trying to find an exploit in a Roblox game. It allows you to give yourself infinite amounts of currency as long as the number is equal or less than 0. I am trying to give myself a positive amount of money.

Since the Roblox lua engine uses double-precision floats, standard integer overflows will not work. Is there any number that can be evaluated as <=0 but is actually >0?

Comment: Do you mean something like: ```print(assert(-0.1<0))```?

Comment: koyaanisqati, I think they mean something like a Lua equivalent to a c++ `uint x = -1;`

Comment: maybe you can achieve interesting results using Nan. Comparing Nan always returns false.